# Checkbox checked on one InfoPath form view but not another?

Tags: infopath, form

I have two new item views on an InfoPath form that add items to a SharePoint list.
On one of them I want a certain checkbox to not be ticked but on another view I want it to be ticked, how can I achieve this? If I set it to true on one view and then false on another both views will have it not ticked.

With for example date fields I go to the other view, select properties of a date field and untick Refresh value when formula is recalculated, what's the equivalence for check boxes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it in Infopath 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have came across this issue where when I set this default checked, it appears unchecked on browser form, As far as I have checked it seems this is the way the logic fields are set on info-path, I mean it is false only if you checked it true. The work around is to reverse the logic of what you need to implement to be false and to be checked true on the form. I dont know if this may help anyway.

Set default false as per your logic to be reverse and when checked true it will work.

Joel Rotich

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I can't see the logic behind this and I wouldn't have thought about it myself. Thanks.